# type inference for a angular util function

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I am currently working in Angular, my HTTP client returns `Observable<HttpResponse<T>>`. I am trying to create a util function that wraps this and returns a `Promise<T>`

```
  const response = await baseResponseHandler(this.api.getAccountInfo('response'); //response is unknown
```

here is the util function:

```
export async function baseResponseHandler<
  K,
  T extends Observable<HttpResponse<K>>,
>(arg: T): Promise<K> {
  const value = await firstValueFrom(arg); //rxjs Observable -> Promise
  if (value.ok) {
    return value.body;
  }
  return value.body;
}
```

Why is it not inferring the type correctly?

Comment: `await baseResponseHandler<ResponseType>(this.api.getAccountInfo('response'));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
export async function baseResponseHandler<K>(
 arg: Observable<HttpResponse<K>>
): Promise<K> {
  const value = await firstValueFrom(arg);
  if (value.ok) {
    return value.body;
  }
  return value.body;
}
```

Now when you call it

```
const response = await baseResponseHandler<myType>(this.api.getAccountInfo('response');
```

Comment: [Pay attention.](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77957301/revisions)

Answer (score 1):

We can just get the type of the API and store it in `T`, then we configure the rest based on this `T` as shown below!

```
import { HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { firstValueFrom, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import 'zone.js';
import { ApiService } from './api.service';

export async function baseResponseHandler<T>(
  arg: Observable<HttpResponse<T>>
): Promise<T> {
  const value = await firstValueFrom(arg); //rxjs Observable -> Promise
  if (value.ok) {
    return <T>value.body;
  }
  return <T>value.body;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <h1>Hello from {{ name }}!</h1>
    <a target="_blank" href="https://angular.dev/overview">
      Learn more about Angular
    </a>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';

  constructor(private api: ApiService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getDummy();
  }

  async getDummy() {
    const response = await baseResponseHandler(
      this.api.getAccountInfo('response')
    ); //response is unknown
    console.log(response);
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-27qglp?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fapi.service.ts,node_modules%2F%40angular%2Fcommon%2Fhttp%2Findex.d.ts&title=Angular%20Starter)